# Find the $T_cM$ and provide a basis for it.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is a repeat of a question I posted but this time I want to go over a specific solution we did in class which I don't fully understand and was hoping you guys could help me out.

Let $c=(0,1,1)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto f(x,y,z):= x^3+y^2-z^2$. Let $M:=f^{-1}(0)$. Find the $T_cM$ and provide a basis for it.

### Solution:

From a previous exercise we found a function $g:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in which its graph parametrizes a part of $f$ containing $c$. Namely let $\alpha:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $\alpha(x,y):=(x,y,g(x,y))$.

**My First Question:** What does this all mean in the paragraph above?

Moving on with the proof...

Since the graph of a differential function is a manifold, we know that $\alpha(B)$ is a $2$-D Manifold. First, we can calculate the differential of $\alpha$ and use it to calculate the tangent space $T_cM=T_{(0,1,1)}f^{-1}(0)$. The formula for $g(x)= \sqrt{x^3+y^2}$. (**How do we find the formula for $g(x)$?**). So $\alpha(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{x^3+y^2})$. The differential of $\alpha$ is a $3 \times 2 $ Matix. (**I am assuming because $\alpha$ goes from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$?**)

$$D_{(x,y)\alpha}= \matrix{1 & 0 \\0 & 1 \\ \frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{x^3+y^2}} & \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^3+y^2}}}  $$

Note: $\alpha^{-1}(0,1,1)=(0,1)$ (**Why?**)

... The proves goes on but I will stop it here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph just means that a neighborhood of $c$ is in the image of $\alpha$ i.e if $y \in B(\epsilon, c)$ for some sufficient $\epsilon$ then $y = \alpha(x_0,y_0)$ for some $(x_0,y_0) \in B$. You get a formula for $g(\textbf{x}) = g(x,y)$ by solving for $z$ in the equation $0= x^3+y^2-z^2$ and here this equlaity is zero since $(x,y,z) \in M$.

Hence, the statement is saying, if $(x,y,z) \in M$, then for $(x,y) \in U$ (for some $U$), we can write $z$ as a differntiable function of $x,y$ i.e $z = g(\textbf{x}) = g(x,y) = \sqrt{x^3+y^2}$.

Comment: Thank you! And how do we get $\alpha^{-1}(0,1,1)=(0,1)?$

Comment: Due to the first two coordinates of $\alpha$, this function is automatically injective and so $\alpha(0,1)= (0,1,1) \Rightarrow \alpha^{-1}(0,1,1) = (0,1)$ i.e this point is the unique pre-image. Observe that this is not the case for a function like $f = x^2$. Here $f(-2) = 4$ but $f^{-1}(4) = \{-2,2\}$.

Comment: Is this okay now? If so, you can accept to close the question.

Comment: got it, yes. I appreciate it